# CSS3 Transform and iFrame (webkit) - Animation stops when user switches to a new tab and back

Tags: css, webkit, cross-browser, css-transitions

I have need to display CSS3 animated content inside an iframe. It seems that when a user switches to a different tab and back - Safari mainly, but some have reported issues in Chrome as well - that the animation returns to the start point and the transform never plays out.

Some other notes with this: this seems to only happen occasionally. Also, in some instances switching tabs multiple time will cause the transform to resume where it should have left off the first time the user blurred tab focus.

Known browser defect or something that I've overlooked? I've tried applying transform-origin and backface-visibility just for thoroughness, but these were of no help.